# PostgreSQL full-text search: how do i scope it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Mostly this is based on RailsCasts screencasts, #341.

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL full text search, and it works, but I need to scope it. Search should go through objects where `object.state=='saved'`.

In screencasts method for search is defined like class method, so I can't use 'where' because 'where' returns Array, and search method is class method, so error here. I tried to change it this way:

```
def test_search(query)
 if query.present?
  self.where("title @@ :q or text_for_test @@ :q", q:query)
 else
  scoped
 end
 end
```

to:

```
@tests=Test.where(:state=>'saved')
@tests.test_search(params[:query])
```

But than Rails throws undefined method error.

What else can I do to scope my search? Or how do I fix error of this attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Use [textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) gem which gives full-text search for postgres.

You can use the "basic_search" function given by textacular similar to how you use named scopes.

```
Test.basic_search('Sonic').where(:status => 'saved')

Test.where(:status => 'saved').basic_search('Sonic')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
where("title @@ :q or text_for_test @@ :q and state @@ :state", q:query, state:'saved')
```